# JenkinsFile how to query if job exists

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a declarative Jenkinsfile how can you determine if a job exists?

I want to conditionally run a stage if another job exists, like so:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'mylabel' }
  // Run the the stages:
  stages {
    stage('Pre-Build') {
      steps {
        timestamps { ansiColor('xterm') { sh 'build/jenkins_prebuild.sh' } }
      }
    }
    stage('Pre-Build') {
      steps {
        timestamps { ansiColor('xterm') { sh 'build/jenkins_build.sh' } }
      }
    }
    stage('Trigger Remote If Exists'){
    when { JOB_EXISTS }
      steps {
        timestamps {
          ansiColor('xterm') {
            sh 'build/pre-trigger.sh'
            build job: "../myjob/foo", wait: false, parameters: [booleanParam(name: 'FOO', value: true)]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, what should I do for JOB_EXISTS?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("YOUR_JOB_NAME") != null) {

}
```

You may not be able to use the above snippet in your declarative pipeline. But you should be able to use this in a global shared lib.

UPDATE:
An administrator needs to approve this snippet in "Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval" section.

Comment: Is this better or worse than `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job)`? This would not look in the current folder, but is `jenkins.model` better? Still subject to script security, right?

Comment: Hi @StephenKing, I'm not sure about that. Need to check that out. But I think, both are subject to script security.

Comment: You can omit the explicit null check, I just used it like this: `if (Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job)) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

There is also this option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076776/3384609

````
try {
    println("Preparing to build the ${jobName}...")
    build job:"${jobName}", propagate:false, wait:false
} catch (hudson.AbortException e) {
    println("Not building the job ${jobName} as it doesn't exist")
}```
````

Comment: Instead of `catch (NullPointerException e)` I had to just use `catch (e)` to get it working. I assume it is the same as `catch (Exception e)`, apparently it is not a NPE (anymore) that is thrown.

Comment: Actually, to be more precise, it's better to use `catch (hudson.AbortException e)`. I just found this, reading the source code: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerStepExecution.java#L67 - however the same type of exception is thrown when the downstream build fails, so there might be no real advantage over `catch (e)`.

Comment: You can omit `propagate: false` when set with `wait: false`.

Comment: This solution is better, as it does not require scripting permission. `try...catch` is slower but that's acceptable when out of the "happy path".

Comment: Is there a way to to do the same, but without triggering the job?