# How to build a Jenkins job from pipeline ignoring if the job doesn't exist?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build a job from my Jenkins pipeline like this:

```
 build job:"${jobName}", propagate:false, wait:false
```

Here ${jobName}  is a multi branch pipeline job and as such may sometimes not exist in my workflow.

This step marks my build as failed if the job doesn't exist. 
Is there a way to simply ignore and move on if the job doesn't exist?

I tried to check whether the given job exist or not like this:

```
    if(jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("${jobName}") != null) {
        println("Preparing to build the ${jobName}...")
        build job:"${jobName}", propagate:false, wait:false
    } else {
        println("Not building the job ${jobName} as it doesn't exist")
    }
```

However, this at times fails (due to script security?).
Is there a better way of doing this?
All I need is to build a job only if it exists.

Comment: script  security can be checked at the In process script approval section of Jenkins Management.

Comment: If you use a scripted pipeline, you can add a try-catch block

Comment: Hi @Prikkeldraad, thank you very much for your comments. I tried your try-catch block suggestion and it works flawlessly. Can you please add this is an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a scripted pipeline, you can add a try-catch block:

```
try {
    println("Preparing to build the ${jobName}...")
    build job:"${jobName}", propagate:false, wait:false
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    println("Not building the job ${jobName} as it doesn't exist")
}
```

Comment: Instead of `catch (NullPointerException e)` I had to use `catch (hudson.AbortException e)` to get it working. See source code: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerStepExecution.java#L67 - however the same type of exception is thrown when the downstream build fails, so there might be no real advantage over `catch (e)`.